# pipenv install jupyterlab => "dependencies could not be resolved"

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv

I'm confused about the correct remedy for the following:

Starting from a virgin pipenv (no Pipfile or Pipfile.lock):

```
$ py -m pipenv --python 3
Successfully created virtual environment!
Created a Pipfile for this project...
$ py -m pipenv install jupyterlab
Installation Succeeded
Resolving dependencies...
[    ] Locking Failed!
...
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Disabling PEP 517 processing is invalid: project does not have a setup.py
```

Since this was a clean install, what dependencies are there that can't be resolved?

I took the suggestion to try `pipenv install --skip-lock` followed by `pipenv graph`, but didn't see any obvious problems in the (enormous) graph.  Or is the real problem a lack of `setup.py`?

Regardless, what's the right remedy?

Answer (score 0):

Root cause was a lack of a Rust compiler under Windows.  So the cure:

1. Make sure you have Microsoft Studio (and C++ build tools) installed
2. Make sure you have Rust installed.
3. Retry the `py -m pipenv install jupyter` command.
   It took a while, but that's what worked for me.